# How to get User's avatar after Facebook API was changed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an issue the relates with Facebook API. Before, I can use the graph api like that to get user avatar

```
//graph.facebook.com/giuliana.roeffero/picture?type=large
```

But now I got this issue

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Cannot query users by their username (giuliana.roeffero)",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 803
   }
}
```

So now, I need to use the User ID instead of User Name, like this

```
//graph.facebook.com/100001473111658/picture?type=large
```

And my question is Can we get the User Avatar by User Name via Facebook API now? If not, how can I get the User Id by User Name?

Answer (score 3):

You can´t get the username at all, it was removed from the API. The only way is to use the (App Scoped) ID, just as you mentioned in your question. So this is how you get the Avatar:

- Authorize the User (with no additional permissions) to get his App Scoped ID
- use `https://graph.facebook.com/[User-ID]/picture` to get his Avatar